# Data structure for Camelcase search (similar to Eclipse and Idea)

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to implement an algorithm for camel case search (skipping letters between capital letters), for example:
Given list and input string.

List:

- ManualProxy.java
- MapPropertyBase.java
- MaxProduct.java
- ManualProviderBase.java
- Map.java

Input:

- "Ma" - we should return all words from the dictionary because all of
  them starts with Ma
- "MaP" - return all except "Map.java", because they start with "Ma"
  and the second word starts with "P"
- "MProd" - return MaxProduct.java because the first word starts with
  "M" and the second words starts with "Prod"

I consider to use a trie, but the problem is that I need traverse the whole tree to find the second capital letter. Another option is to use trie for capital letters and tries for nodes. But in this case, I have to return from the node and if there are matches continue traverse for the next capital letter.

Is there any better approach to this problem?

Comment: Is regular expression a solution?

Comment: I think it's too costly to apply the re on each filename. I'm trying to find something that is faster

Comment: can you clarify the rule a bit more? For example, "MP" will match   "MabcPabc", but will it match "mPMabcPabc"? How about digit, is it allowed to appear in the strings and how to treat them?

Comment: You can split MabcPabc into two subwords: Mabc and Pabc. Whenever you start writing a capital letter, you can skip the rest of the current subword and go matching the next subword. Camel case assumes all words start with the capital letter